# UIDocumentInteractionController doesn't show up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to present a `UIDocumentInteractionController` from a navigation controller, when the user selects a file from the `tableView`.

The `interactionControllerWithURL` returns NO and the delegate method `documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview` is never called and the `documentInteraction` controller does not appear.

The following code is executed when the user selects an item in table:

```
    NSURL *fileURL;
    fileURL = (NSURL *)[[DataMng sharedMng] getFileInFolder:self.navigationItem.title atRow:indexPath.row type:type];

    if (self.docInteractionController == nil){
        self.docInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
        if (!self.docInteractionController) {
            NSLog(@"Selected a file with estension not supported for visualization");
            return;
        }
        self.docInteractionController.delegate = self;
    }else{
        self.docInteractionController.URL = fileURL;
    }

    if(! [self.docInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES]){
        NSLog(@"ERROR in presenting preview");
    }
```

The delegate controller (self) conforms with `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` protocol and is a navigation controller inside a `Tabbar` controller.

Any ideas will be welcome

Answer (score 9):

I answer my own question:

the form I was launching the docInteractionController was correct, the problem was in the file url, which lack the correct extension (.pdf in my case) and in the controller UTI, which must of the extended form (com.adobe.pdf).

Once correctly set the preview was displayed without problems.

Answer (score 2):

you use these methods to show UIDocumentInteractionController:-

```
-(UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller

{
    return [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]window]rootViewController];

}

-(void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:    (UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller 

{

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(! [self.docInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES]){
        NSLog(@"ERROR in presenting preview");
    }
```

Think, this is not the right way to present document interactionController. Try setting the below code

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
[self.docInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I understood from the documentation that the method "presentOpenInMenuFromRect" was to: prompt the user only to open the file in another app. Anyway I tried this function but it does not works for me.

Comment: I realized that any call to present the DocumentInteractionController returns NO (I edited the question). Do you know for what reasons it could be unable to present the file (PDF) ?

Comment: Try setting `inView:self.view.window` on for `inView:self.view`

Comment: Not working. It keeps returning NO. Is there any way to understand if it is a problem of views or a problem of the file to be previewed?